# set or show date in textbox with jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have problem to set or show date in datepicker textbox at firsttime
I have two textboxes, the one is for datepicker and the second is for alternate format.

```
<input type="text" id="birth_date_display" />
<input type="text" id="birth_date" />
```

and scripts like this

```
$( "#birth_date_display" ).datepicker({
 dateFormat: "d M, yy",
 altField: "#birth_date",
 altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

my question is, How if i have String like: var datebirth="2011-08-16" 

then i want to set to the textbox.

i had try to make script like this:

```
document.getElementById("birth_date_display").value = datebirth; //it's NOT works
document.getElementById("birth_date").value         = datebirth; //it's works
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [setDate method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate) on the DatePicker:

```
$( "#birth_date_display" ).datepicker("setDate", datebirth);
$( "#birth_date" ).datepicker("setDate", datebirth);
```

*Edit: You could probably also do it this way, but I haven't tested it:*

```
$( "#birth_date_display, #birth_date" ).datepicker("setDate", datebirth);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the [setDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-setDate) DatePicker method. This will set the value of the DatePicker and update both text box elements with the appropriate value in the formats you specified for the dateFormat and altFormat.

```
var datebirth="2011-08-16"; 
$("#birth_date_display").datepicker("setDate",new Date(datebirth));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to format month names instead of integer

```
var Month = "Feb" //some month; 
var Year = "2013" //some year; 
var mydate = new Date('1 '+ Month + " " + Year);
```

$(".txtDate").datepicker('setDate', new Date(Year, mydate.getMonth(), 1));